# recursively finding friends of friends etc

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find the names of all of my friends, then the names of all of their friends, out to 4 degrees. I need to track which degree a friend is from me however (eg direct friend=degree 1) I have some code, but I dont really understand how to solve this problem. Any advice would be great.

```
def getFriendNames(name)
    ret=Array.new
    #lots of code here, doesnt change the problem

    return ret #returns unique list of friends names
end


arr=Array.new
friends=getFriendNames("ME")
arr.push(friends) #element1 of the array arr is now friends of ME. Element 2 should be friends of friends of ME
friends.each{|x|
    getFriendName(x) #this returns another array of friends
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a conceptual question, that has a definite answer (I just dont know it). It isnt homework (im working with a large psychology datset for research), and I included my (bad) attempt at a solution

Comment: what you want here is called recursion, a function which calls itself for each next layer and returns what it has fetched, level is passed as second argument, just read about it anywhere, start from wiki page for recursion for example.

Comment: @EugenePetrov I think it's more accurate to describe this is a graph search algorithm (for a given node, find all nodes with distance at most 4, and their shortest distance). Recursion is one way to solve such problems, but it isn't the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it is the most simple and direct one that came to mind.

```
friends = Hash.new
to_process = ["ME"]

(0..4).each { |distance|
    processing = to_process
    to_process = []

    processing.each { |person|
        if !friends.has_key?(person)
            friends[person] = distance
            to_process.concat(getFriendNames(person))
        end
    }
}
```

---

If you want to keep track of the "source" friend then instead you could write:

```
friends = Hash.new
to_process = ["ME"]

4.times {
    processing = to_process
    to_process = []

    processing.each { |source|
        getFriendNames(source).each { |person|
            if !friends.has_key?(person)
                friends[person] = source
                to_process.push(person)
            end
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it's possible in reality to have more than one "source" friend. For example if you have `A` and `B` as friends and both of them have the friend `C`, then `C`'s source friend could be either `A` or `B`.

Comment: `getFriendNames` returns an array.

Comment: @Max you are absolutely correct. I tested with `+=` in the repl and I'm not quite sure why I changed to `push` instead of `concat` when copying the code.

Comment: @user4987274, if I wanted to record the names of the people they are friends with instead of their distance from the starting person is that possible?